# This set minimize the minimum?

Tags: optimization

Let $S$ a finite set and let $A \subseteq S$ and $B \subseteq S$.

We can say that $Z = B$ minimize the following minimum:
$$\min_{Z \subseteq S} \{|A \cap Z| + |B-Z|\}$$? If yes, why?

Answer (score 0):

First, show one direction: $|A\cap B| \ge \min_Z \{|A\cap Z|+|B-Z|\},$ because you can always try $Z=B$.  Now to show
$|A\cap B| \le |A\cap Z|+|B-Z|$ for any $Z$.  You can always add to any given $Z$, all the elements $z\in (B-Z)-A$ and only decrease the right-hand side (you'll be making the 2nd term smaller).  Then add anything $z\in (A\cap B) - Z$ which will not change the right-hand side.  Remove any $z$ outside of $A$ and $B$. You end up with $Z=B$.

Answer (score 0):

For $i\in S$, let binary decision variable $z_i$ indicate whether $i\in Z$.  The problem is to minimize
\begin{align}
\sum_{i\in S} \left([i\in A] z_i + [i\in B] (1-z_i) \right)
&= \sum_{i\in A} z_i + \sum_{i\in B} (1-z_i) \\
&= \left(\sum_{i\in A \setminus B} z_i + \sum_{i\in A \cap B} z_i\right) + \left(|B| - \sum_{i\in A \cap B} z_i - \sum_{i\in B \setminus A} z_i\right) \\
&= \sum_{i\in A \setminus B} z_i + |B| - \sum_{i\in B \setminus A} z_i
\end{align}
Now it is clear that every optimal solution must satisfy:
$$z_i=\begin{cases}0 &\text{if $i\in A \setminus B$}\\1 &\text{if $i\in B \setminus A$}\end{cases}$$
For all other $i \in S$, you can set $z_i$ arbitrarily.  In particular, $Z = B$ is one of the optimal solutions.